# Can I get from my nuxt.js project - list of all my potential routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Can I get from my nuxt.js project
- list of all my potential routes?
(all of my URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nuxt app will create a router which will include an Object with all routes available to your app. You can find the created router in your `.nuxt` folder if I am not mistaken.

Also, in your nuxt Config you have the `router` key, which allows you to customize the behavior of `vue-router`. Read more here: [Vue-Router Documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router)

You can access the router in components under `this.$router`. All generated routes are accessible at `this.$router.options.routes`.